# Using RealtimeMultiplayer google play services with out achievements. is that ok?

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer

i am working on a game using RealtimeMultiplayer game using google play services. just added achievements as dummy and not used those on my application, any issues with that on configuration side. i am not able to login after installing application from play store. i followed the help document placed on android website.[image]

Comment: did you sign with a release key and keep the google play games authentication with the debug keystore?

Comment: login is working fine on testing .. but when i published to live its not working ... yes .. using Export signed Application package .. created new keystore and created APK .. after that using zipalign .. converted it aand uploaded on PLay store and published.

Comment: anything i missed inbetween, please update me

Comment: in the play games console did you add an android app with the settings of the release keystore signed app

Comment: i think it asks you for a SHA1 fingerprint when you add the app

Comment: @JRowan  - yes i added that while i am adding package information to google play services .. i updated SHA1 fingerprint ..after that using that appid .. i am able to test .. but when i published with same details, i am not able to login

Comment: did you publish the game play services?

Comment: it should be ok because if you were going to put achievements in in an update, achievements should have nothing to do with it